# JSON formatting to show multiple list items in same row

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting

I am using JSON formatting to change the view of modern SP List, I have referred
[this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting) article

I was able to achieve both the examples but in first example they are showing each item in one row.

Can we display multiple tiles side by side, Side by side tile view is shown in second example but for that every user has to manually select tile for menu to view it.

Is there any way we can achieve the side by side tiles to display multiple list items in same row?

Comment: Seems you want https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/view-samples/generic-tile-format?

Comment: Yes, but for this user has to manually select tile option from menu, I want this to be coming by default to every user

Answer (score 0):

You could save the Tiles view as a new view and set it as default.

[image]

Comment: I have set it to default, for me its showing tiles, but for other users it is still showing list items as in all items view. This view is not set default view for other users

Comment: Find the user voice https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/17365024-ability-to-set-tile-or-list-as-a-default-view, have to custom SPFx to build as 'Tiles' similar as https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-starter-kit/blob/master/documentation/components/wp-tiles.md currently.